# Tidying Data using Loops across multiple data.frames

Tags: r

I'm a beginner trying to understand R for the first time and had a series of questions that I had problems finding answers to whilst learning R.

The problem that I've come across are the following

1. How can I create a loop to filter out certain aspects of my data?
2. How can I import a large amount of .CSV's from a folder then apply a loop to get rid of extra data and filter out data including setting the variable name as their file names?

This is essentially the filter that I want but I need to apply this to a series of .CSV files and output this to new csv file.

```
rainfallg1 = read.csv("120015A.csv",
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
            sep=",",
            rainfall_filter <- rainfallg1[,1:3])

# This section names the columns and numerically codes them making it easy to filter.

names(rainfall_filter)[1] <- "Time_Date"
names(rainfall_filter)[2] <- "Rainfall"
names(rainfall_filter)[3] <- "Code_of_Standard"

rainfall_filter$Rainfall <- as.integer(rainfall_filter$Rainfall)
rainfall_filter$Code_of_Standard <- as.integer(rainfall_filter$Code_of_Standard)

rainfall_filter_1 <- filter(rainfall_filter, Code_of_Standard <= 83)
```

Comment: How many of these "120015A.csv" files are there, and do they obey an obvious naming convention?

Comment: @anguyen1210 there are over 1000 of the files however the name changes however keeps the same form in terms of 6 numerical values and one associated alphabetical value.

Comment: Nevermind my asking, just saw @Ronak’s answer below which solves this issue easily using list.files() and map(). Solution is good...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of all filenames  using `list.files` and apply the function using `lapply`/`map`

```
library(dplyr)
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

purrr::map(filenames, ~.x %>% 
                #Read the data
                read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
                #Select only first 3 columns
                select(1:3) %>%
                #Rename the columns
                setNames(c('Time_Date', 'Rainfall', 'Code_of_Standard')) %>%
                #Change `Rainfall` and  `Code_of_Standard` columns to integer
                mutate(across(Rainfall, Code_of_Standard), as.integer) %>%
                #keep only rows less than equal to 83 in Code_of_Standard
                filter(Code_of_Standard <= 83) %>%
                #Write the csv file.
                write.csv(paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(.x)), 
                          '_new.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
      )
```

This should write new files in your working directory. If your old files are called `df1.csv` and `df2.csv` this would write `df1_new.csv` and `df2_new.csv`.